# Octroire or Octroyer

Tags: grammaire, verbes, lexique

Is it correct to say:

> "Pour octroire à quelqu'un la totalité des privilèges administratifs"

I found this sentence in an official documentation and I wonder if this is correct.

Comment: Welcome to FSE. I've already posted an answer. Just from curiosity: where did you find this?

Comment: Il ne faut pas croyer tout ce qui est écrit dans les documents officiels... ;-)

Comment: @Dimitris if you search for it in google you find the source

Comment: @jlliagre I might add your comment in my answer:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Sure. Here is another one (not mine): *Ne disez pas disez, disez dites !*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the word 'octroire' does not exist:

1. https://1mot.net/octroire
2. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=octroire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Most probably a typo I guess. It should have been 'octroyer'.

**EDIT**

To quote @jlliagre :

> Il ne faut pas croyer<sup>1</sup> tout ce qui est écrit dans les documents officiels  ;-)
>
> Ne disez pas disez, disez dites :-)!

<sup>1 croire</sup>